# Sieve of Eratosthenes C++ Implementation: not exiting loop

Tags: c++, math

I'm trying to implement the Sieve by myself and with no help other than the algorithm provided...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void findPrimeNumbers(int number) {

    int n=0;

    bool* boolArray = new bool[number](); 

    for(int i=0; i<number; i++) {
        boolArray[i] = true;
    }

    for(int i = 2; i<(int)sqrt(number); i++) {
        cout << "calculating...\n";
        if(boolArray[i]) {
            for(int j=(i^2+(n*i)); j<number; n++)
                boolArray[j] = false; 
        }
        if(boolArray[i])
            cout << i << "\n";
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{

    findPrimeNumbers(55);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Except the program is hanging on line 37; specifically, "boolArray[j] = false". It's never exiting that loop, and I don't know why.

Edited: Ok, this fixes the hang but still isn't right, but don't answer, I want to figure it out :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void findPrimeNumbers(int number) {

    int n=0;

    bool* boolArray = new bool[number](); 

    for(int i=0; i<number; i++) {
        boolArray[i] = true;
    }

    for(int i = 2; i<sqrt(number); i++) {
        if(boolArray[i]) {
            for (int j = pow(i,2) + n*i; j <= number; j = pow(i, 2) + (++n*i))
                boolArray[j] = false;
        }
        if(boolArray[i] && number % i == 0)
            cout << i << "\n";
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{

    findPrimeNumbers(13195);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i^2+(n*i)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: You test `j<number`, but increment `n`...

Comment: related: [an example of Sieve of Eratosthenes implementation in C++](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#C.2B.2B)

Comment: There are a ton of trivial implementations of this sieve, [this begin one of them](http://ideone.com/PxaFMf). I would suggest a side-by-side comparison to see where you're off (you may be surprised).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the line `i^2+(n*i)` like the comments point out, `operator^` is the XOR operator, not exponentiation. In order to exponentiate something you have to include the `<cmath>` header and call `std::pow(a,b)` where it is equivalent to the mathematical expression `a^b`.

Although you didn't ask for code review, it should be noted that using dynamic allocation for a bool array is probably not a good idea. You should use `std::vector<bool>` and a proper `reserve` call. It should also be noted that the `pow` call would be completely unnecessary, as you are only multiplying it by itself (i.e. 2^2 is the same as 2*2).

A better naive prime sieve would be something similar to this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> generatePrimes(unsigned int limit) {
    std::vector<T> primes;
    std::vector<bool> sieve((limit+1)/2);
    if(limit > 1) {
        primes.push_back(2);
        for(unsigned int i = 1, prime = 3; i < sieve.size(); ++i, prime += 2) {
            if(!sieve[i]) {
                primes.push_back(prime);
                for(unsigned int j = (prime*prime)/2; j < sieve.size(); j += prime)
                    sieve[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return primes;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<unsigned> primes = generatePrimes<unsigned>(1000000);
    for(auto& i : primes)
        std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

You can see it [here](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=58d1a8fdac88c983464364ca5a8f7c89).

Comment: Ok, I'll try using pow, and tell you guys the results.

Comment: `i^2` can be changed to `i*i` without the need to use the `pow` function.

Comment: I updated my code now. I figured out what I was doing wrong, too. Thanks. It still isn't right though; I'll try doing that myself, though.

Comment: Don't use a `std::vector<bool>`. Use `std::bitset` instead.

Comment: @Yuushi I'm pretty sure `std::vector<bool>` is specialised from a regular `std::vector<T>` though. I could post my `std::bitset` prime, but it unfortunately crashes if the upper limit is too high (100 million or higher) while the `std::vector<bool>` equivalent doesn't.

Comment: @Rapptz It is specialized, but the problem is that `std::vector<bool>` isn't a container. It pulls some annoying tricks under the covers and can have some really nasty surprises in store. See http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/050.htm - also, why bother templating this?

Comment: @Yuushi For memory of your choice, you could remove the template if you wanted to and make it unsigned, doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the error pointed out by @Rapptz (^ is bitwise xor), you are incrementing n instead of j, so the termination condition is never reached.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of problems:

```
int j=(i^2+(n*i))
```

`^` is not power in C++, it's the bitwise XOR operator. To fix this, you'll need to `#include <cmath>` and utilize `pow`, or simply use `i * i`.

Secondly, as others have mentioned, you are incrementing `n`. The easiest fix for this is to use a `while` loop instead:

```
int j = std::pow(i, 2) + (n*i);
while(j < number) {
    //Set bool at index to false
    j += i;
}
```

Thirdly, you have a memory leak - you `new` without a `delete`. Further, there's no reason to use `new` here, instead you should have:

```
bool b[number];
```

This will deallocate b automatically when the function exits.

Finally, why `return` at the bottom of a `void` function? Technically you can do it, but there is no reason to.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

The `^` operator is not the exponent operator like it is in some other languages.  Just multiply `i` by itself instead (`i*i`).

your `for` loop:

```
for(int j=(i^2+(n*i)); j<number; n++)
    boolArray[j] = false;
```

does not reevaluate the initial condition each loop.  You need to reevaluate the condition at the beginning of the `for` loop:

```
for(int n=0; j<number; n++)
{
    j=(i*i+(n*i));
    boolArray[j] = false; 
}
```